# Weird behavior with gwan v3.12.26

Tags: g-wan

I just installed the latest Xmas gift from gwan team, but I'm having some problems:

1. Segmentation fault with archlinux .
2. On Ubuntu strange behavior.
3. I can't run any script on it.

About #1, Archlinux is up to date and uses the 2.16 GLIBC.

About #2, I'm loading `http://188.165.219.99:8080/100.html` sometimes it display 100 X, sometimes an error page (with CSS) and sometimes an error page without CSS.

About #3, I can't run any csp script:

```
http://188.165.219.99:8080/?hello.c
http://188.165.219.99:8080/?hello.rb
http://188.165.219.99:8080/?hello.php
```

None of the above work. Has the csp url changed?

I have installed php5-cli and ruby on my ubuntu.

For informations:

```
# ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11) 2.11.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Here the log on archlinux

```
# cat logs/gwan.log 
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] G-WAN 3.12.26 64-bit (Dec 26 2012 13:58:12)
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] Local Time: Thu, 27 Dec 2012 16:03:44 GMT+2
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] RAM: (1.60 GiB free + 0 shared + 834.57 MiB buffers) /   23.64 GiB total
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] Physical Pages: 1.60 GiB / 23.64 GiB
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] DISK: 1.71 TiB free / 1.88 TiB total
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] 336 processes, including pid:1545 './gwan'
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] Multi-Core, HT enabled
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] 1x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU W3520 @ 2.67GHz (4 Core(s)/CPU, 2 thread(s)/Core)
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT]   using   4 workers 0[1111]3
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT]   among   8 threads 0[11110000]7
[Thu Dec 27 14:03:44 2012 GMT] 64-bit little-endian (least significant byte first)
```

Comment: I have encountered similar problems as in (2). JS and CSS files are either partially sent by G-WAN or not sent at all. I have sent test cases to Pierre. It should be resolved soon. I only use the C API and my csp folder only contains c scripts. My C project compiles and links fine, only the static files are an issue.

Comment: Have the same on Debian 2.6.32 - GWAN 4.1.24. It loads anything thorugh time, 200/404/200/404

Answer (score 0):

> 1: segmentation fault with archlinux

Many informations are listed at the top of the /logs/wgan.log file. It would immensely help to see it (that's what log files are for).

> 2: on ubuntu strange behavior

Not knowing the nature of the "strange behavior" nor the Ubuntu version makes difficult to answer your question (if that's a question).

> 3: I can't run any script on it

We received more than 50 emails this morning alove. None (but yours) reports that scripts fail to run. So far, people report great results with all languages.

Check your files permissions (can the G-WAN account *read* the script files?) and verify that the relevant compilers / runtimes are installed.

---

Ogla's report suggests that javascript embedded in HTML (the new release does minifying there) migh be the cause of the cut files.

---

Other than that, the fact that the **daemon mode** is broken in v3.12.25/26 may explain your problems if you run in daemon mode.

Comment: Ok it looks like my old ubuntu version is the issue ... everything works fine on my VM (ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: You truncated the most relevant part of the *requested* gwan.log file... so ideas are hard to provide. You could also email a coredump to G-WAN's team, that would say where the crash happened.

Comment: This is because it don't contain anything else !!

Comment: Interesting: that is cut just before the OS name (are you using a virtualizer?). Please contact G-WAN by email so we can tell you how to make a test to pinpoint the bug.